# laravel passing a variable to js file from a controller

Tags: laravel

I have a js file located in assets folder (not View). can i pass a varible from a controller?

In view file:
The Js is called like this

```
<canvas id="chart1" class="chart-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible (in my point of view) to put a variable to external JS file. You can use data-... attributes and get values from html elements.

For example you can pass your PHP variable as a json encoded string variable in your controller.

```
$data['chart_info'] = json_encode($chart_info);
return view('your_view', $data);
```

Then put it in `data-info` like this.

```
<canvas id="chart1" class="chart-canvas" data-info="{{ $chart_info }}"></canvas>
```

And finally in JS, you can get the variable and decode (parse) it as following.

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('chart1');
let info = JSON.parse(canvas.dataset.id);
console.log(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put that part of the Javascript in the view and send the variable to the same view. For example, add a section in view:

```
@section('footer')   
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script> 
@endsection
```

Do not forget that you should add `@yield('footer')` to the end of your layout view.

Comment: Thanks it worked i was putting the code in head instead of footer

Comment: I prefer JavaScript code to be at the bottom of the code due to the heavy load on the site. Also, if my answer was useful to you, please vote up for me. Good luck.

Comment: did it... but low reputation.. so i don't know if it will count

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to mix javascript and PHP/Blade, it might be hard to read the code in the future... You could use a different approach, loading the chart with a async ajax request.
You will have to create a end-point that returns the data you need for your chart:

Your router:

```
Route::get('/chart/get-data', [ ControllerName::class, 'getChartData' ]);
```

Your controller method:

```
public function getChartData() {
    $chartData = [];
    // Your logic goes here
    return $chardData;
}
```

In your javascript (using jquery) file there will be something like that:

```
function loadChartData() {
    $.ajax({
        'url': '/chart/get-data',
        'method': 'GET'
    })
    .done((data) => {
        // Load your chart here!!!
    })
    .fail(() => {
        console.log("Could not load chart data");
    });
}
```

Hope I helped ;)